# is there a service/api to manage web based feedback from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get feedback on a webpage. There are 2 types of feedback I am looking for:

1. click a button (which sends something like a rating) - no other
   interaction
2. submit a form with details

I don't want to do any server side coding.  I realize I can't do that with only javascript.

Is there any third party service or api I can use to collect and view this feedback?

If you have any custom solution which doesn't require a lot of effort/learning I would be interested.

Comment: Define "feedback". Also "If you have any custom solution which doesn't require a lot of effort/learning I would be interested." I would suggest rent-a-coder.com

Comment: You can think of something like a rating - suppose I provide buttons 1 to 5.  clicking on that sends me an email with the context (URL/custom text).

Answer (score 1):

qualaroo.com might be what you need. you can embed it to your site. Also surveymonkey.com has embedding options for your web site.

Comment: Qualaroo seems interesting.  However, I don't want to pay right now.  I was also looking for something really micro - click on a button, sends the context and response to the backend.